# Electric field of a full disk - when $R \to 0$ - it's not equal to coulomb law

Tags: electrostatics

An [MIT document states](http://web.mit.edu/8.02t/www/materials/InClass/IC_Sol_W02D1_4.pdf) that the electric field of a full disk, when $R \to 0$, is similar to Coulomb's law

> $$\mathbf E_{disk}=2\pi k_e\sigma\left[1-\frac{x}{\left(x^2+R^2\right)^{1/2}}\right]\hat{i}=\frac{\sigma}{2\varepsilon_0}\left[1-\frac{x}{\left(x^2+R^2\right)^{1/2}}\right]\hat{i}$$
>   Either version is fine, its just a different way of writing the constant. You should also check the limits: for $R\to0$ (but keep $Q$ constant!) it should go to a point charge. For $R\to\infty$ (infinite plane) it should be a constant.

Though, I don't think that it works that way, it is easily seen that when $R \to 0$, then $\mathbf E_{disk} = 0$.

Can somebody help me figure out how to arrive at the stated result - what am I missing to get the field of a point charge when the disk size goes to zero?

Comment: But when $R \to 0$ you have no more charge. The charge on a surface equal to zero is $\sigma \cdot 0 = 0$.

Comment: @Sofia: why the "but" ? I think similar to you :) I don't understand why did they write that. What are we missing here?

Comment: Aaaa! I apologize, I didn't notice that you keep $Q$ constant when shrinking the radius. But if so, the formula is different, $\vec E = \frac {Q}{\pi R^2} \left[1 - \frac{x}{\sqrt {x^2 + R^2}}\right]$. So, when $R \to 0$ you get $\frac {0}{0}$.

Comment: When you take the limit $R\rightarrow 0$ you cannot simply plug in $R = 0$.

Comment: This is the setup for a good question but it doesn't actually ask anything, so I'm closing it. Dor, can you edit to make clear what you're asking? Once you do it'll be reopened.

Comment: @DavidZ - I have taken the liberty of turning this into a question.

Comment: @DavidZ: Hi David, the question is now clear. Please reopen. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, but now it seems rather close to our [homework policy](//meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) (note that this applies to more than just homework) which doesn't allow questions where you present a problem and ask how to solve it and nothing else. I think it'd be a much better question if you asked _why_ the limit of the field as $R\to 0$ is not zero. That said, it's not a big deal just one time; it's more as something to keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that we keep leading order terms. So for the second part of the expression in parentheses, as $R \rightarrow 0$, we don't just get 1. Using the taylor expansion, we get
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{R^2}{x^2}}}\Rightarrow 1 - \frac{1}{2}\frac{R^2}{x^2}+....$$
Plug this into the original equation while remembering $\sigma= \frac{Q}{\pi R^2}$ gives
$$ \vec{E}_{disc}= \frac{\sigma}{2 \epsilon_0}\left[\frac{R^2}{2x^2}\right] = \frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 x^2}$$
which is exactly the field of a point charge that we want.

Comment: I understand. Only 1 thing left: why choosing to use up to the third item (i.e. 2nd derivative) ? What about the reminder? You didn't plug them into the original equation.

Comment: The next taylor term is proportional to $R^4/x^4$. You could keep this term around and then you would add a term looking like $R^2/x^4$ in the final expression. But remember that we're taking the limit as $R$ goes to zero. If $R$ is small, say $10^{-10}$, then a term that scales like $1/x^2$ dominates the electric field compared to a term like $R^2/x^4$. So we just ignore the extra terms when we find 1 nonzero term, because we can show any extra terms should be small compared to the first term.